# Homotopy equivalence on numerable cover implies homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles

I am interested in proving that a fibre bundle $p:E\to M$ of manifolds with contractible fibres is a homotopy equivalence.
I know that this question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402896/is-a-fibre-bundle-with-contractible-fibre-a-homotopy-equivalence) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477539/total-space-of-fiber-bundle-is-homotopy-equivalent-to-base) by usaing a $CW-$structure on the spaces anche the Whitehead theorem, and these proofs are clear to me.
However, I am also interested in a more "topological" proof. In particular, in a comment to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548714/existence-of-section-on-fiber-bundles-with-contractible-fibers) the user "Tyrone" quotes the following theorem:

> If there exists a numerable covering of $M$ for which each restriction $E|_U \to U $ is a homotopy equivalence over $U$, then $E \to M$ is a homotopy equivalence over $M$.

They gave the following reference: Theorem 7.57 in James's book *General Topology and Homotopy Theory*.
I found the book and tried looking at the proof, but, to be honest, the language used in the book is a bit obscure to me (expecially because this theorem is near the end, so they use a notation that is a bit hard for me to track back in the paragraphs where the definitions are given).
If any of you had a different proof of this fact, or even a different reference, I would thank you very much.
Alternatively, I would aprreciate any possible different solution to my original problem, which does not use a $CW-$structure.